# Azure DevOps Build pipeline failed for DownloadPipelineArtifact@2

Tags: vb.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Build pipeline failed for below DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task in my VB.Net App Deployment.

##[error]No builds currently exist in the pipeline definition supplied.

[image]

Code for DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 task in azure-pipelines.yml file is displayed as seen below:

[image]

Requesting assistance on the same.

Comment: Are there any runs for the specified build? Do those runs create pipeline artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

That task fails because you havent published an artifact with that pipeline.

you have 2 different ways to publish artifacts:

- publish build artifacts (deprecated) used mostly in classic pipelines

  - can only be downloaded with download build artifact step
- publish pipeline artifacts are used to publish an artifiact available for this same build or another pipeline

  - can only be downloaded from a download pipeline activity

You need to publish your build using publish pipeline artifact first (check if not already).

So first check the source pipelien with definition 370 from Project StarsDemo, and see if the latest build published an artifact or had an issue.

Also, per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops), the runId is required (aka pipelineId, buildId).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing **runVersion** value to ***latest*** instead of ***latestFromBranch*** , after which the pipeline build successfully.